# Prevent resize of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ipad

I try to implement a custom split view for an iPad application.

On the left side, I have a ViewController which contains the navigation. 
The right side should contain a NavigationController with a navigation bar. When I initialize the NavigationController, I set the frame to the correct width:

```
FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    [firstView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(186, 0, 838, 748)];
    [firstView.view setAutoresizesSubviews: NO];

UINavigationController navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstView];
        [navController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(186, 0, 838, 748)];
        navController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Title";
```

But somewhere between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear the frame.width from navController.view changes back to 1094 px. And so my title label is not correctly centered (within the visible area). Can I prevent the NavigationController from resizing? I already tried setAutoresizesSubviews: NO but this doesn't seem to work.